# is there any way to import file from another parent folder css react js

Tags: css, reactjs, import, directory, filesystems

[image]

this is my files, in my **Sidebar.js** that is in the component folder, i need to import sidebar.css from styles folder, components and styles are in parent folder sidebar.

pls give me a solution

Comment: where are you trying to import sidebar.css to?

Comment: got the answer bro, importing css file to sidebar.js

Answer (score 0):

Seems, you are looking for this: `import "../styles/sidebar.css"` ?

Answer (score 0):

Try this way

sidebar.css

```
import { StyleSheet, Platform } from "react-native";

export const sidebar = StyleSheet.create({});
```

Sidebar.js

```
import { sidebar } from "../styles/sidebar";

class Sidebar extends React.Component {
  clickMe() {
    alert("Hi!");
  }
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="box" onClick={this.clickMe.bind(this)}>
        Hello {this.props.name}. Please click me.
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```